# I want to second element of column i.e Heading to take accessibility focus first when talkback is on but it getting focus on close button in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following view in compose

[[image: Layout]]

When Screen loads in accessibility mode talkback talks about close button first but i want it should talk about heading first.

I have tried following solution

```
Column{
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val focus = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
CloseButton{
//Something about close button
}
TextView{
modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    if (!focus) {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                        focus = true
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Also tried this

```
Column{
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
CloseButton{
//Something about close button
}
TextView{
modifier = Modifier
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
    }
}
 LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            this.coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        }
```

But both are not working

Comment: The first solution worked! only need to add some delay there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Modifier.semantics { traversalIndex = 1f }` on the close button to ensure it gets focused last. Or you can set the `traversalIndex` on every composable to set a fully custom focus order (the order is from smallest to largest `traversalIndex`).

Comment: This works. but this needs to be upgraded to compose 1.5.0. Thank you